# How do I get someone at Salesforce to address my certification questions?

Tags: support, certification

I went to take an exam over a week ago and didn't find out until it was too late that you can only use the Mac OS with a certain version, and I didn't have it. Since I didn't know until the minute of the exam I couldn't take it. I've tried contacting certification support via phone; (415)836-2420 and email; certification@salesforce.com but they never get back to me. This happened once before too, and it was well over a couple months before I received an email back, and then another 2 weeks after I responded to that. I've talked to others having this same issue, some don't hear back at all.

Any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest your Account Executive and Twitter (@SalesforceCert).

Comment: I've asked my acct exec exec about it, but she hasn't heard back. I also just had SE tweet it. Thanks